# Convert string with variable delimiters to dataframe R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some text (a string copied from a website) and would like an easy way to convert it into a dataframe with two different columns. The real data contains many more rows than detailed here.
The main issue is that the string has a variable number of delimiters (spaces) in what should be the second column. Is there a quick and easy way to go from the raw data to the desired output? Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou.

**Raw data (string)**

```
my_text = "Column_1  Column_2
    01  do something
    02  do something else 
    03  do the same
    04  do something very different"
```

**Desired output (dataframe)**:

```
Column_1  Column_2
01        do something
02        do something else 
03        do the same
04        do something very different
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the string into `L` at which point it is a vector of lines, trim the whitespace off the ends, replace the first sequence of spaces with comma on each line and then use read.csv.  If you want Column_1 to be numeric omit the colClasses argument.  (If the text can itself have commas then use a different character than comma in the sub and specify it using sep= in the read.csv.)

```
L <- readLines(textConnection(my_text))
read.csv(text = sub("\\s+", ",", trimws(L)), colClasses = "character")
```

giving:

```
  Column_1                    Column_2
1       01                do something
2       02           do something else
3       03                 do the same
4       04 do something very different
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one base R option -

- Drop the headers (`sub('.*?\n', '', my_text)`) by deleting text till first `'\n'`.
- Split the string on new line character.
- Using `strcapture` capture the data in two columns. First column extracts the numeric part and the second column captures everything after that.

```
strcapture('\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(.*)', 
           strsplit(sub('.*?\n', '', my_text), '\n')[[1]], 
           proto = list(Col1 = character(), Col2 = character()))

#  Col1                        Col2
#1   01                do something
#2   02          do something else 
#3   03                 do the same
#4   04 do something very different
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution based on `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(
   Column_1 = unlist(str_extract_all(my_text, "\\d{2,}")),
   Column_2 = unlist(str_extract_all(my_text, "(?:\\s)[a-z][a-z\\s]+[a-z]"))
)
```

Here, `\\d{2,}`makes sure you do not match the single digits after `Column_`; the non-capturing group `(?:\\s)` asserts that the lower-case text with interspersed gaps `[a-z][a-z\\s]+[a-z]`be preceded by whitespace (which prevents matching the lower-case parts of `Column`)

Result:

```
df
  Column_1                     Column_2
1       01                 do something
2       02            do something else
3       03                  do the same
4       04  do something very different
```